# How to set ValueSerde per Binding Spring Cloud Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to set valueSerde per binding, however only default valueserde is being considered.

AppSerde class

```
public class AppSerdes {

    public static final class DepartmentSerde extends WrapperSerde<Department> {
        public DepartmentSerde() {
            super(new ProtobufSerializer<>(), new ProtobufDeserializer<>(Department.class));
        }
    }

    public static final class EmployeeSerde extends WrapperSerde<Employee> {
        public EmployeeSerde() {
            super(new ProtobufSerializer<>(), new ProtobufDeserializer<>(Employee.class));
        }
    }

    public static final class DepartmentDataSerde extends WrapperSerde<DepartmentData> {
        public DepartmentDataSerde() {
            super(new ProtobufSerializer<>(), new ProtobufDeserializer<>(DepartmentData.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**StreamsConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class StreamsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BiFunction<KStream<String, Employee>, KStream<String, Department>, KStream<String, DepartmentData>> process() {
        return (Employee, Department) -> Employee.leftJoin(Department, (v1, v2) -> {
            if (v2 == null) {
                log.info("No Department is present");
                return null;
            } else {
                var data = DepartmentData.newBuilder();
                data.setId(v2.getId());
                data.setName(v2.getName());
                data.addEmployees(v1);
                return data.build();
            }
        }, JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1))).peek((k, v) -> {
            log.info("Key->{}, value->{}", k, v);
        });
    }
}
```

and application.yml

```
spring:
  application.name: kafka-join-example
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: 192.168.56.101:19092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$EmployeeSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-out-0.producer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentDataSerde
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    process-in-0:
      destination: kp.sch
      consumer:
        use-native-decoding: true
    process-in-1:
      destination: kp.lm
      consumer:
        use-native-decoding: true
    process-out-0:
      destination: kp.lm.sch
      producer:
        use-native-encoding: true
  kafka.streams.bindings:
    process-in-0:
      consumer:
        value.serde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$EmployeeSerde
    process-in-1:
      consumer:
        value.serde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentSerde
    process-out-0:
      producer:
        value.serde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentDataSerde
  kafka.streams.binder:
    brokers:
    - 192.168.56.101:19092
#    replication-factor: 3
#    required-acks: 2
    min-partition-count: 5
    configuration:
      commit.interval.ms: 100
      default:
        key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        value.serde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.kafka.serde.ProtobufSerde
```

---

### Edit

Full sample code is [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/kafka-join-example)

```
**stack trace**2020-12-06 21:55:39.929 ERROR 141897 --- [-StreamThread-1] 

o.a.k.s.p.i.AssignedStreamsTasks         : stream-thread [kafka-join-example-4aa10729-e5b7-4a33-89c6-906dd8ab2e5d-StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 1_4 due to the following error:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=1_4, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001, topic=kp.department, partition=4, offset=1, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:45)
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:26)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:100)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:400) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:160) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:56) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:26) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:100) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:55) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:104) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]

2020-12-06 21:55:39.930 ERROR 141897 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [kafka-join-example-4aa10729-e5b7-4a33-89c6-906dd8ab2e5d-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=1_4, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000001, topic=kp.department, partition=4, offset=1, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:45)
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:26)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:100)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:400) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: No target type provided
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.github.kprasad99.streams.protobuf.serialization.ProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(ProtobufDeserializer.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:160) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:56) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredWindowStoreIterator.next(MeteredWindowStoreIterator.java:26) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKStreamJoin$KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKStreamJoin.java:100) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamJoinWindow$KStreamJoinWindowProcessor.process(KStreamJoinWindow.java:55) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:142) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:201) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:133) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:104) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$3(StreamTask.java:383) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:806) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:383) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:475) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:550) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:802) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670) ~[kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your configuration a little bit, this should work. If it doesn't please create a small sample app and share, then we can look at this further.

```
spring:
  application.name: kafka-join-example
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers: 192.168.56.101:19092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$EmployeeSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-out-0.producer.valueSerde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.AppSerdes$DepartmentDataSerde
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    process-in-0:
      destination: kp.sch
    process-in-1:
      destination: kp.lm
    process-out-0:
      destination: kp.lm.sch 
  kafka.streams.binder:
    brokers:
    - 192.168.56.101:19092
#    replication-factor: 3
#    required-acks: 2
    min-partition-count: 5
    configuration:
      commit.interval.ms: 100
      default:
        key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        value.serde: io.github.kprasad99.streams.kafka.serde.ProtobufSerde
```

You can also define these beans in your application as below.

```
@Bean
public Serde<Department> departmentSerde() {
  return new DepartmentSerde();
}

// add the other two Serde beans.
```

If you define these `Serde` beans in the application, then you don't need the 3 corresponding `valueSerde` properties in the configuration as the beans get priority.

Comment: updated as per suggesstion, it works for first param(process-in-0) for second param(process-in-1) it still takes default serde, due to which I'm getting error, since in default serde I'm not passing type information. code sample is here https://github.com/kprasad99/kafka-join-example

Comment: I think you are hitting the same issues as in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003575/spring-cloud-kafka-cant-serialize-data-for-output-stream-when-two-processors-a/65082204?noredirect=1#comment115069862_65082204

Comment: See my answer there. This issue is already addressed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/5a7cc9f257374989df7f3862d7009cac34d4a3f4. If you can update to this latest snapshot, it should correctly infer the Serde.

Comment: I'm still getting the above error, updated the code to latest snapshot version, and made sure the fix is present on that class, still getting same error.... for second parameter default value.serde is considered.

Comment: I will have to take a look and get back to you later.

Comment: Should I create a issue in github?

Comment: Yes, please go ahead if you think that this is an issue. I still haven't gotten a chance to look at your code.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad I ran your code and I can see that the binding `process-in-1` gets the correct `Serde`. However, I think the issue that you are running into is not related to inbound serialization. The issue is with your business logic. There you have to use the correct `Serde` for the `join` call. The binder cannot infer such `Serde`s needed inside the application's code.

Comment: You need to use the correct overloaded method for `leftJoin` that takes the `Serde` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks alot.. added serde to leftjoin it worked. Appreciate your help.  Cheers.